# NGINX: Rewrite numeric URL segment with prefix

Tags: nginx, redirect, regex

I'm aiming to have some old URLs work with the new CMS we're migrating to, but it can't support purely numerical URL slugs for some reason, so the new system has them as "/calendar/event/old-42" instead of "/calendar/event/42". I'd like to redirect these purely numerical URLs to their new slugs. Here's what I had in mind to do that:

```
location ~ /calendar/event/(\d+)$ {
  rewrite ^/calendar/event/$1$ /calendar/event/old-$1 permanent;
}
```

This seems to not be working, and just 404s when I go to "/calendar/event/42". Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this location:

```
location ~ ^/calendar/event/(?<slug>\d+)$ {
    rewrite ^ /calendar/event/old-$slug permanent;
}
```

You don't need to do complex regex matching in `rewrite`, when all necessary stuff is done within the `location` regex. One possible reason for the rewrite failing is the use of numerical variable from location.